# Смысл от перегрузки метода SetProperty с Action в который нельзя передать объект

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

В классе `BindableBase` есть 2 перегрузки метода

```
bool SetPropetry<T>(ref T storage, T value, string propertyName = null);
bool SetPropetry<T>(ref T storage, T value, Action onChanged, string propertyName = null);
```

Не вижу в чем смысл данной перегрузки? Если это перегрузка для того что бы к примеру повесить callback на сторонний `View` или `ViewModel`, то в чем смысл передавать `Action<void>`, если мне необходимо сослаться к примеру на ссылку какого то объекта текущей `ViewModel`, или передать данные для валидации `Model`?

Простейшие перегрузки методов которые мне необходимы:

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T, T2>(ref T storage, T value, Action<T2> onChanged, T2 obj,
    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (!SetProperty(ref storage, value)) return false;
    onChanged.Invoke(obj);
    return true;
}

protected virtual bool SetProperty<T, T2>(ref T storage, T value, Action<T2> onChanged,
    ref T2 obj, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (!SetProperty(ref storage, value)) return false;
    onChanged.Invoke(obj);
    return true;
}
```

> Q: Почему возник такой вопрос?
>
> A: До этого пользовался исключительно `Catel`, в котором изначально было описана одна реализация установки значений полям, и оповещении подписчиков.

P.S. Я знаю что могу самостоятельно сделать свою перегрузку в которую запихну этот самый `Action<T>`, Но я все же не понимаю зачем было так делать?

Comment: За что минус то? Очень интересно

Comment: Не знаю призм, но если это классический Set<T> в MVVM, то по идее это калбэк который вызовется при *реальной* смене значения. А этого может и не быть, ведь есть проверка на равенство с предыдущим.

Comment: @vitidev что никакого отношения не имеет к вопросу автору. :) Он спрашивает, почему используется `Action` вместо `Action<T>`

Comment: Мы же можем в качестве `Action` передать лямбду, а эта лямбда может захватить что угодно, вуаля, параметр не нужен

Comment: @Андрей, да, но передать объект по ссылке в другую `ViewModel` нельзя будет :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, никаких проблем я тут не вижу.

Проблемы в том, чтобы «засунуть» дополнительные параметры в `Action`, нет: вы просто делаете замыкание по нужным параметрам (например, `() => ProcessOnPropertySet(this)`). А вот на стороне фреймворка проблемы есть, потому что непонятно, какие именно параметры вам нужно передать.

Вы хотите весь объект? Вы хотите новое значение свойства? Вы хотите проверить и возможно *изменить* значение свойства? Вы хотите отправить событие? Всё это можно легко выразить через `Action` при помощи замыкания.

А если мы хотим избавиться от замыкания, то фреймворку нужно заранее угадать, какие параметры вам понадобятся. И самостоятельно определить нужную вам перегрузку. А это не так просто, потому что у каждого проекта свои, специфические требования.

Поэтому универсальное решение с `Action` вполне катит.

Comment: Т.е. передать в `Action` `Action.Invoke`, или любой другой метод, и так уже проводить все эти операции?

Comment: @Birdy: Передать, скажем, `() => ProcessOnPropertySet(this)`.

Comment: Вот! Это точно нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Birdy: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 5):

Данный вопрос следует задавать разработчикам Prism, но никак не в этом комьюнити.

Не бывает идеальных API, которые бы устраивали всех. Тем не менее, это явно не худший пример, так как у тебя остаётся возможность реализовать собственную обёртку и передать менее общий делегат.

Можно взглянуть на классический подход WindowsForms-приложений, в которых коллбеки строго ограничены сигнатурой `(Object sender, EventArgs args)`. Легко найти такие варианты использования, в которых передаётся `this`, `null`, 'new EventArgs()' и т.д. И люди точно так же задаются вопросом - зачем так было делать?

`Prism` наследует принципы .NET Framework и предоставляет минимально достаточный API, который программисты могут расширять для своих нужд. В данном случае такая возможность есть.

Comment: `Можно взглянуть на классический подход WindowsForms-приложений, в которых коллбеки строго ограничены сигнатурой (Object sender, EventArgs args)`, разве это ограничение? Наследовать класс `EventArgs`, и добавить необходимые данные.

Comment: @Birdy необходимость наследования от базового класса - это самое страшное ограничение из возможных, так как в .NET отсутствует множественное наследование, а значит в качестве аргумента ты не сможешь передать ничего, кроме EventArgs. С `sender` ещё забавнее. Мало того, что он не гарантирует безопасность типов, так ты ещё и не знаешь, что в него положат - `null`, `this` или что-то ещё. Например, событие `Changed`, которое может быть инициировано элементом управления, его владельцем, приложением, которое загружает настройки и т.д. В итоге получаем опасную и непонятную конструкцию.